# Why there is gap of 15 days in Shravan Maas of North Indians and Maharashtrians?

Tags: india, history

I'm pretty much aware of Shravan Maas, we don't eat non-veg and alcohol; some people don't even shave but why there is a gap of 15 days in Shravan Maas of North Indians and Maharashtrians?

Comment: What do you mean by a gap?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think he means that if North Indian starts Shravan Maas say today, than Maharashtrians start after 15 days or vice versa...

Comment: This blog has more exlanation about purnimant and amavasyant calendar types. http://hinducalendar.alokm.com/p/calendar-type.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Hindu month consists of one full lunar cycle, either from full moon to full moon, or new moon to new moon, which would be ~ 28 days. The period from the *Purnima* to *Amavasya* takes ~14 days, and is called the *Shukla-paksha*, or the bright half of the month. From the *Amavasya* to *Purnima* is another 14 days, which is called the *Krishna-paksha*, or the dark half of the month.

North Indians follow the *Purnimant* calendar, ie, the month begins with the *Purnima* or the full moon, till the next full moon. In the North Indian calendar, the *Shukla-paksha* of the month comes first, followed by the *krishna-paksha*. Maharashtrians & South Indians follow an *Amavasyant* calendar, ie, the month begins from *Amavasya* or the New Moon, where the *krishna-paksha* comes first, followed by the *shukla-paksha*.

Comment: Why don't you explain the reason north Indian's follow the Purnimant Calander and others don't(Maharastrians and South Indian's don't)

Comment: Valarko - Krishna paksh is the fortnight with fading moon ie.. from Poornima to Amavasya. Shukla paksh is fortnight with brightening moon ie.. from Amavasya to Poornima

Comment: You stated wrong. North indians follow Purnimanta- the month starts from krishna paksha and ends on sukhla paksha. & south indians follow Amanta- the month starts on purnima & ends on Amavasya. You stated exactly oppposite.